# Building a Search Functionality with Efficiency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, search, typesense

I have a collection in mongo-db the structure of which is given below

```
{
_id: 1,
order_no: '2512',
materials: [
{
material_type: 'A',
material_id: 2,
},
{material_type: 'B',
material_id: 3,
}]
}
```

Similar to this structure we have a lot of information/fields about materials and we have to build a search functionality on these fields. I need some alternatives to explore for this problem statement. Some of the alternatives I am already exploring are TypeSense and ElasticSearch. Any more efficient methods to solve this?

I am already exploring Elastic Search , Type Sense and AWS DocumentDB. Need some other or better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using the cloud-based search service like Azure Search. This service provide a fully-managed search platform that you can integrate with your MongoDB collection using APIs or connectors. It also offers features like automatic scaling, search analytics, and customizable search relevance algorithms.